# What should I use to convert to unicode, po2prop o native2ascii?

Tags: java, unicode, properties, translation

I want to do a simple task, convert a file encode in iso-8859-1 to UNICODE. According to the java specs at [docs.oracle.com](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/prop2po)

> Characters less than \u0020 and characters greater than \u007E in
>   property keys or values are written as \uxxxx for the appropriate
>   hexadecimal value xxxx.

Looking at the internet it seems that native2ascii is quite old and has problems, while the [translation toolkit](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/toolkit/prop2po) (and po2prop) are much better.

How can I do a straight translation for a a file with characters like "à" so it gets translated into \00e0 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00e0/index.htm)?

I've been looking at this for quite a lot of time and haven't been able to find a proper answer.

Comment: why can't you just read the file in using an inputStreamReader set to iso-8859-1 and then output in unicode similarly?

Comment: I was looking for something such a standalone binary. The files I try to convert are the translations of an opensource project. I am not a good coder, so I'm looking for something straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you could see how I handled various input text stream types (including UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1) and various output text stream types (including UTF-16) in my `crlf` utility I wrote a while back. The program has an option to convert control characters as `\udddd` character sequences.

It's at:
 http://david.tribble.com/src/crlf.cpp
 [http://david.tribble.com/src/src.html](http://david.tribble.com/src/src.html#crlf)

Be forewarned that it's written in C++, not Java.

Comment: I was testing your code under my system -> g++ (Debian 4.6.3-1) 4.6.3
And I get this:
  In file included from crlf.cpp:65:0:
  textstream.hpp:143:34: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘;’ token
  textstream.hpp:146:14: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘;’ token
  textstream.hpp:147:32: error: invalid pure specifier (only ‘= 0’ is allowed) before ‘;’ token

Comment: Eesh. Replace `= NULL` with `= 0`. C++ syntax sucks in many places.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty hack you can encode the string as JSON and strip off the end quotes. Not really sure how properties like the other usual JSON escapes though...

Comment: Could you provide me a program to do that? I would like to avoid having to code something that problably has been done (much better) a million times.